# Dropdown list to click item to display bold in textbox then type normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When type text display dropdown list click it will display Bold letter in textbox then type continuously normal letter allowed only not bold letter without button.

Eg.  **Java**world

```js
 $(function(){
    var availableName = ["Java","Javascript","PHP","HTML","CSS","Angularjs","SQL",".Net"];
    $( "#uname" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableName
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue; 
  color: Darkblack;
}
h2 {
  color: #000080; 
  font-size: 300%;
}
.name{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <form align="center">
        <br> <label for="name"> Name: </label>
        <input class="name" type="text" id="uname"> <br>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: This code is ok. But i need type java click list it will display java then type script JAVA Highlighted (BOLD) letter script normal form.

Comment: Type remo select that name.Display bold letter inside input field then type same input field it should display small letters @TylerH

Comment: Ex: **Java** is already insert code world is own word. So i need Java displayed bold letter inside name field. Other letters displayed normal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at my solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/32Bck/340/)

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $("#suggest").autocomplete({
    delay: 100,
    source:["Java","Javascript","PHP","HTML","CSS","Angularjs","SQL",".Net"]
  }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    var term = this.element.val(),
        regex = new RegExp( '(' + term + ')', 'gi' );
    t = item.label.replace( regex , "<b>$&</b>" );
    return $( "<li></li>" ).data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append( "<a style='height:30px;'>" + t + "</a>")
        .appendTo( ul );
  };
});
```

Hope this will help you !.

Comment: Type Ja it will display drop down list select Java not bold letter ?